# How can i store and access flash symbols in a database?

Tags: flash, facebook

just like facebook game, I see that even I am playing facebook social game, it still have some downloading when I click on an item for the first time, or just by doing something new. Is that people can divide flash into many parts and connect them when they need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly it, you can use dynamic loading of data (images, text, binary data, xml as well as other .swf's (flash files)) to load things as you use/require them. It's done by all the programs you use daily, when you open a textfile, movie, webpage etc.

For now, start with something simple, like loading an image into flash.

This is actionscript 2. It's a big tutorial, but at least it spells everything out.

http://flashexplained.com/actionscript/loading-external-jpgs-into-your-main-swf-movie/

And if you want to research it a little bit more:

http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHNY_srRS374RS374&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flash+dynamic+loading

Add in "image" or "text" or "xml" or "swf" or whatever behind the search term to find more tutorials on that...

Good luck.